# JQM : disable form submission on enter press while in text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, webforms

I have a text box in the form, Then this checkbox is focused and I press enter the form is submitted. however This is not the behaviour I want. I want to validate the form and manually send it only on clicking a certain link or pressing an enter outside the text field. Here is code of my form

```
<form action ="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'Queue','action' => 'checkinupcoming'))."/?confirmnumber=$this->confNumber&clientid=$this->clientId";?> " data-ajax="false" method= "post" class="checkin-form">     
                <h3>Customer Details</h3>

                <ul class="form" style="margin:  10px 0 15px 27px">
                        <li id="descriptionLiId" class="first last descriptionLi">
                                <label id="lbldescriptionId" class="lbldescription">Description</label>
                                <input id="descTextId" class="descriptionText" tabindex="1" type="text" name="description" title="Enter visually identifying description" value="Enter visually identifying description" onfocus="onFocusBehavior(this);" onblur="onBlurBehavior(this);" />
                        </li>
                </ul>

                <h3 id="hdrnotesId" class="hdrnotes">Notes</h3>

                <ul class="form">
                        <li id="notesListId" class="first last notesList">
                                <textarea id="notesId" class="text-area notes" tabindex="1" name="notes"></textarea>
                        </li>
                </ul>
</form>
```

I am submitting the form by serializing the input and sending a jquery ajax request. I want to disable the form submission on enter button when the text field is focussed

Answer (score 0):

solved this by disabling the enter press

```
$('.descriptionText').bind('keypress', function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is to use  `onsubmit="return false"` at form tag so there is no need for extra jQuery.

```
<form action="" data-ajax="false" method= "post" class="checkin-form" id="form1" onsubmit="return false">
```

but be careful when using this method, you should submit form manually like this :

```
<input type="button" value="manual submit" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit()" />
```

and about your code please note that it is recommended to use e.which instead of e.keycode

> [It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/)